# Return true in JavaScript when call function from OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I use this code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Block" Text="text"  OnClientClick="return BlockCheck()"   OnClick="BtnBlockClick"  CausesValidation="False"/>


function BlockCheck() {
            if (x) {
                document.getElementById('#ErrorText').text('Error');
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
```

but this for this part : `document.getElementById('#ErrorText').text('Error');<br>`to 
return true.

Comment: What is `x`? Where is is defined?

Comment: x is condition that true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need `#` in getElementById's param: it really should be written like this...

```
document.getElementById('ErrorText')
```

With `#` that'll try to find an element with ID literally equal to `'#ErrorText'`- that'll fail, so the function will return `null`. And any attempt to work with `null` afterwards (calling some methods off it, in particular) will fail with an Error raised.

Second, you seem to mix jQuery functions and JavaScript ones: there's no `text` method in DOMElements. Strictly speaking, you'll have to check for `textContent` support, then go with it; if it's not supported, use `innerText` instead. For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('ErrorText');
el['textContent' in el ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'] = 'Error';
```

Apparently the check's not required if your project doesn't have to support IE8-.